# Need SQL Injection Document?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

i am trying to study **SQL Injection** nowadays & i am searching for good tutorial . 

any recommendation for written or videos tutorial ?

Comment: I think you need to offer a bit more detail.  We often combine UI, network traffic, stub feeds and sql as part of testing.  The easiest is the latter.

Comment: Closing as an apparent duplicate - if the other question isn't what you're asking, then please add some more details to distinguish this question clearly from the one linked by Twaldigas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest for any security related testing you start with OWASP:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

OWASP have excellent overviews and descriptions as well as concrete guidance on testing and mitigation for most common classes of vulnerability.